# SQL Server Converting Decimal into Time hh:mm, I need the total hours

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2, data-conversion

I need to be able to get the total hours and minutes if it is over 24 hours from a decimal column in SQL Server.

This is the code I am using:

```
CAST(CAST(DATEADD(SECOND, 1654.86 * 60, 0) AS Time(0)) AS VARCHAR(5))
```

Since it's over 24 hours the output is "03:34" I would like for it to be "27:34" or if possible to tell me it will take 3 working days and "03:34" (not sure how that would work).

Thank you in advance! Paul

Comment: `time` isn't an interval, it's a *literal* time; as in the time of day. You can't store a value of 24 hours or more in a `time`; you would have to use a formatted value in a string based data type.

Comment: Realize that "time of day" and "time span" are two *separate* concepts, and you're trying to work with a "time of day" data type. There's no "time span" data type in SQL Server. Perhaps move this closer to the presentation layer which likely *does* have such a data type.

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the comments, the `time` data type is not designed to represent any sort of interval or timespan, it is only designed to represent clock time. As such, it is not capable of displaying 27 hours. Instead you need to build this string yourself with methods other than simple `CAST as type`:

```
DECLARE @d table(decimal_column decimal(15,2));

INSERT @d(decimal_column) VALUES(1654.86);

SELECT d.decimal_column, 
       nice_time = CONVERT(varchar(11), FLOOR(h)) + ':' 
                   + RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(varchar(11), FLOOR(m)), 2)
FROM @d AS d
CROSS APPLY
(
  VALUES(d.decimal_column/60, d.decimal_column%60)
) AS extracted(h,m);
```

Results:

| decimal_column | nice_time |
| --- | --- |
| 1654.86 | 27:34 |

- Example [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=8c3c6408f2e3ba78f3577a0620faaa4c)

You may have edge cases where you want actual rounding logic instead of `FLOOR()` - but if you have those cases, include them in your question so we know the desired output.

Comment: Thank you Aaron! I was hoping I could keep it in datetime format since I was going to store it into that datatype, oh well I will just have to create another column with carchar datatype. Thanks again!

Comment: @Paul This makes no sense to me. How are you going to store `27:34` in a datetime column? Why don't you store the start and end time? Then you can always derive things like 1654.86 and 27:34 by inspecting the difference.

Comment: Well the decimal numbers are actually coming from a calculation which calculates how many minutes it takes to completed an order. Sorry if I confused you, I was hoping I could it keep it as DateTime when I started this thread and was hoping there was a way but from your explanation and the guys above, I realized now that you cant store 27:34 in datetime.

Answer (score 1):

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, 1654.86/60)) + ':' 
+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, 1654.86-(CONVERT(INT, 1654.86/60)*60)))
```

You can create a function for this query, it is very performance.  Because we will not use the same operations in multi sections.

Comment: What operations are being used in "multi sections" and can you show why that's bad for performance? Also please don't recommend people use `varchar` without specifying a length ([background](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length)).

Comment: In my code, I use `CONVERT(INT, 1654.86/60)` in 3 different places,  so this command will execute 3 times. But, using the function we can use variables (declare) which, we can set the result of `CONVERT(INT, 1654.86/60)` this command to our variable and can use it anywhere in the function. Example:  `declare @k integer  set @k = CONVERT(INT, 1654.86/60)   select  CONVERT(VARCHAR, @k) + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(INT, 1654.86-(@k * 60)))`

Comment: Do you know that SQL Server will actually execute that three times? It's pretty good at reusing constants and expressions. And even if it does, do you know that executing that three times is more expensive than retrieving the value from a variable reference?

Comment: Maybe, but I always believe that the code should be written in such a way that if you suddenly need to accidentally switch to another `DB`, that would not cause problems. Each "DB" has a different query planning mechanism.

Comment: Each db also has different data types, different ways to declare variables, and different ways to create functions. Repeating an expression is going to be the least of your worries if you need to change your code to work with Oracle or MySQL tomorrow. :-)